# Is there a way to multiply all the elements of an array using thrust?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Let's say I have an array and I want to multiply all the elements of that array and store it in a variable. How do I do it? I want to multiply all the elements in A and store the result in S. Doing this gives me zero.

```
thrust::device_vector<double> A(10);
thrust::sequence(A.begin(), A.end(), 1);
double S = thrust::reduce(thrust::host, A.begin(), A.end(), 
                             0, thrust::multiplies<double>());
```

Comment: Leaving aside the  `thrust::host` execution policy, which is wrong and should be excluded, what value to do expect if you initialize the product to 0? I expect 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The use of the `thrust::host` execution policy makes no sense (in fact no execution policy makes sense if you are using thrust vectors as inputs). I would expect some sort of segfault or runtime error if you actually tried to run this code. Use tag based execution instead, i.e. just remove the first argument, and thrust will infer the execution policy from the types.
2. The fourth argument in the `thrust::reduce` in call your code is the *initial value* of the product. You are setting it to 0. This means any product calculated by that code will be zero. Presumably you want the initial value to be one.

Fixing both of those glaring problems gets me this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<double> A(10);
    thrust::sequence(A.begin(), A.end(), 1.0);

    for(auto p = A.begin(); p != A.end(); ++p) {
        double v = *p;
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    double S = thrust::reduce(A.begin(), A.end(), 1.0, thrust::multiplies<double>());

    std::cout << "S = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << S << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running it gets me this:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o prodprob prodprob.cu 

$ ./prodprob 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
S = 3628800.0
```

The correct answer should be 10! = 3628800, so I judge this as working correctly.